# Mazda 6 2014 sport

Tags: battery-drain, acceleration, jump-start, mazda-6

The last week in a half my Mazda 6 has been having issues with starting at first you could hear it would have a tough time starting like there was not enough power going to the car to get it going but it would start and after a few mins run fine. The other day I could not get it started at all I had my friend come and jump it and once it was started it seemed fine I ran a few errands where I would only leave the car for a few mins shut off and when I went to start vit it would start but was doing that thing again where it didn’t want to and barely would turn over the last time I got in it and started it I stared driving the car right away and the car jumped like the gear was messed up and the whole after that it was it was having problems accelerating every time I would have to stop at a light or slow down and the radio was flashing off and my check engine light came on along with my traction control light. I got it home but and didn’t drive it yesterday so this morning I went out to start it my freind had to come back and jump it for me and when I start driving it it was having the problem with execration again so I pull over and let it sit for awhile running after a awhile I drive it again and it was driving normally again. Tonight my friends took the battery out and put it on a charger to check it and also charge it the battery didn’t say it was bad and it taking the charge but it’s not saying that it maintaining it so I didn’t know if it was the battery that is bad or if something else is going on to drain it ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your best bet with your battery is to take it to a big chain automotive store and have them test it for you. From your description, either the battery is done, or the system is not charging. To me, there's definitely a problem in one of the two areas.

Comment: Totally agree with @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - if this is the original battery (and it sounds like it might be), it's well past its warranty and expected life. Good news, though: if it's the battery, you should know right away (when you replace it)!